# Hidden navigation items despite correct Audience Targeting (SP Online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, navigation, groups, audience-targeting

I want to hide some navigation items (custom links) from my navigation bar only for a defined user group in my sharepoint online. So i activated audience targeting. But since I activated it, all navigation items with selected audience targeting are hidden, despite I am a member of the target group. When I navigate to "Start" I can still see all the navigation items.

Any ideas what the problem can be?

Regards,
Jan

**//edit 1:**

Here is a screenshot of the navigation configuration:

[image: screenshot of the navigation configuration]

And this is a screenshot of the hidden navigation result:

[image: screenshot of the hidden navigation result]

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable audience targeting for navigational links just as this [tutorial](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-navigation-news-and-files-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)? Only office 365 group works for it.

You need to edit the link and add your group into the audience targeting groups. I tested in my end it works fine. Would you like to provide some screenshot?

Comment: I updated my first post and added screenshots. As you can see I added the administrtion user group, which is a office 365 group and which I am part of, to the navigation, but the result is still a hidden navigation item :-(

Comment: @JanWorpenberg Yes I see that. I will suggest you to open a service request for this issue.